# Setting listview adapter on fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, adapter

Hello I'm trying to set up so I have a list view represented on a fragment on my application currently if I attempt to run the app with my it will crash if its on a fragment but if its on a main activity it will work. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I have to change to the final piece of my code to get it to work on a fragment

The code below represents my main activity and its XML which works as it should

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List <Wine> lstWine;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    createData();

    ListView lvWine = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lvWines);

    WineAdapter adapter = new WineAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview, lstWine);
    lvWine.setAdapter(adapter);




}


public void createData(){

    lstWine = new ArrayList<Wine>();

    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blushshs", "Random", "MONEY"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush",  "Random", "String"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "fffffffffffffffffffffff", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "fffffffffffffffff", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));






}
```

---

The code above I have tried to convert above to that I could apply it an a listview within a fragment.

```
  public class winelistfragment extends Fragment {

List<Wine_String> lstWine;
Inflater inflate;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    wineListData();

    ListView lvWine = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testlistview);

    WineAdapter adapter = new WineAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_winelist, lstWine);
    lvWine.setAdapter(adapter);



}

public void wineListData(){

    lstWine = new ArrayList<Wine_String>();

    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blushshs", "Random", "MONEY"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush",  "Random", "String"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "fffffffffffffffffffffff", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "fffffffffffffffff", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));



}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wine, container, false);
```

---

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to change fragment code?

Comment: post the logcat of the crash please.

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be throwing a null pointer exception because you are trying to retrieve the view id for your ListView (R.id.testlistview) in the onCreate() method of your Fragment. This is because the onCreate() method is called before the onCreateView() method of your fragment which is where you should inflate your views. Since the view does not yet exist at the point where you are creating your fragment, you end up with the crash. You are extracting the element correctly after the view is set in the Activity but you need to change your code in the Fragment.

Basically, you need to inflate your view in the onCreateView() method in the Fragment without which you will have no view (currently your case). Once this is done, then you can extract the view element in the onViewCreated() method of your Fragment and then set the values. For more information on the lifecycle of Fragments, I would recommend going through the following link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. The link shows you how to instantiate your views and then extract them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I did was made a list fragment and then added this list fragment to the xml of the fragment page that I required.

```
public class List extends ListFragment {

java.util.List<Wine_String> lstWine;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    wineListData();



    WineAdapter adapter = new WineAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_winelist, lstWine);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}


public void wineListData() {

    lstWine = new ArrayList<Wine_String>();

    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blushshs", "Random", "MONEY"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "Random", "String"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "fffffffffffffffffffffff", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "fffffffffffffffff", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));
    lstWine.add(new Wine_String(R.drawable.blush, "Blush", "YEAR", "Random"));



}
 }
```